# Complex SQL Update Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got two MYSQL tables "shirts_in_box", "trousers_in_box" which represent two different classes of objects that can be in the same box : shirts and trousers, and the quantities of each box that is present.

The table "shirts_in_box" has columns "shirt_id, quantity" and "trousers_in_box" has columns "trouser_id, quantity"

I've got to deal with the following situation :

1) i start with two items in box_id = "foo" : e.g table "shirts_to_box" has a row

```
shirt_id = 'xxx', quantity : '1'
```

and "trousers_to_box" has a row

```
trouser_id = 'www', quantity : '2'
```

2) an update list of items for box_id = 'foo' is submitted, which looks like

```
trousers_to_box :

box_id : foo, trousers_id : 'aaa', quantity : '5'

shirts_to_box :

box_id : foo, shirts_id : 'xxx', quantity : '2'
```

3) i should take this and update "shirts_to_box", "trousers_to_box" so that the above are ALL the entries in the two tables having box_id = 'foo', ie

```
shirts_to_box :

UPDATE shirt_id = 'xxx', quantity : '1' to quantity = 2

trousers_to_box :

ADD trouser_id = 'aaa', quantity : '5'
DELETE trouser_id = 'www', quantity : '2'
```

At the moment, my method is not very efficient. I make two separate queries on the two separate tables, and make my adds/updates/deletions to each separately.

Is there a way to do this all in one query ? Or even a more efficient way than what I've got at the moment ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a general table `item_in_box`, **with distinct id for all items** (you musn't have the same id for a trouser and a shirt) :

```
-----------------------------------------------
 BOX_ID  |  ITEM_ID  |  ITEM_TYPE  |  QUANTITY
-----------------------------------------------
 foo     |  xxx      |  shirt      |  1
 foo     |  www      |  trouser    |  2
-----------------------------------------------
```

Then when you've got an update for the `foo` box, you just have to use this kind of request :

```
UPDATE item_to_box
SET `quantity` = CASE `item_id`
    WHEN xxx THEN 5
    WHEN yyy THEN 2
END
```

The new column `item_type` is not used in your updates, but will be helpful to differentiate your items.

**EDIT**

To fully generalize your code, here's what I suggest to you :
[image]

Keep your tables `shirt` and `trouser`, but use an intermediate : `item`. You'll now have a single UPDATE request to do, whatever the number of item types you've got (the same one I wrote above).

*Note : the `item.type` column is optional, you can use it to quickly know the type of an item, without querying all child tables (`trouser`, `shirt`...)*

Comment: thanks for your reply ! the problem is that shirt and trouser id's are coming from other tables, and so i can't guarantee there won't be an overlap of id's. Also I don't think this will delete rows that aren't in the new list of items in the box

Comment: The simplest solution would be to use two tables : `item` and `item_type` (instead of `shirt`, `trouser` ...). Then you don't need the `item_in_box.item_type` column anymore, have distinct IDs, and are able to generalize your code.

Comment: hmm and so what would the columns of item and item_type be?

Comment: ok thanks for that ! but is it a good idea to add a whole new table of duplicate data just to make my update easier ? i agree the db architecture wasn't great but i'd love to have a solution that works within what i've got, if possible...

Comment: You shouldn't have duplicated data. The `item` table will only be there to get distinct IDs (and eventually every field which is not specific to a kind of item). With your current architecture, I'm afraid there's no way to make your update in a single query.